# How set ICS theme for application with minSDK 7?

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

could anybody tell me how can I set a theme for my application which will change when version of Android will change. For example if anybody will use my app on Android 2.1 theme will look like this: http://daily-money.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/img/prefs.png

But if anybody will use my app on for example Android 4.0.3 theme will look like this: http://img.tapatalk.com/dcff019c-27ba-1e1a.jpg
I have used minSDK 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is detailed in on this page: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html

In the section titled "Defaults for Older Apps"

You setup 2 theme files, one in the values directory and one in the values-v11 directory.  Then you reference that theme file in the Manifest.  As outlined in the page I linked above.  You need ALL THREE blocks of XML outlined on that page under the "Using Holo while supporting Android 2.x" section.

Comment: I had tried it before I wrote here and it didn't work but I don't know if I used it correctly. Must I add it only to manifest or only to styles.xml or to both files?

Comment: Both, see the additional stuff I added to my answer.

Comment: I can't add those line to /res/values-v11/themes.xml, it writes this error, I think it is because of minSDK 7.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo'.

Comment: You have to set your target SDK to something 11 or higher (Android 3.0 or higher) in your Eclipse Android settings.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I had to set my project.properties to 13, now it works, thank you very much :)

Comment: Can that run the app with ICS theme on 2.x devices or just compatible with older theme?

Answer (score 3):

first get the version of android running on the device :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
```

....

en after you can use setTheme(..) before calling setContentView(...)and super.oncreate() and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

@letroll, what parameter do you pass to setTheme? Does it require increasing min sdk to 13 to make the SDK available?