# ICS style in Froyo and Gingerbread Apps

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.2-froyo

I am developing an application for Android and I'm using the API level 8. However I would like this app would use the theme of ICS when running on Froyo and Gingerbread because the theme of the ICS is much more beautiful. I wish that at least the color scheme and shape of the buttons were equal. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "because the theme of the ICS is much more beautiful" -- bear in mind that other apps do not do this, causing your app to look odd in comparison to the other apps on the user's device.

Comment: The application will support themes. The user can choose which theme to use. However never noticed to much homogeneity in the appearance of apps I use. So I guess I will not be a big problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How set ICS theme for application with minSDK 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732988/how-set-ics-theme-for-application-with-minsdk-7)

Comment: Do not quite understand the question posted and maybe I have betrayed me, but I think it is not the same issue. If I posted a duplicate question I'm sorry, but I have not found one similar. I would make an app with ICS style even in early versions of Android.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing you might want to look at is ActionbarSherlock as it adds a lot of consistency to your pre-ics code, even though this is not directly related to the theme.

Then take a look at the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) project on GitHub for using the Holo theme on apps designed for pre-ics devices.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I look for! I had read something about ActionbarSherlock. It seems very interesting. I'll look more closely.

Answer (score 5):

The best i found is [android-holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) in which you will get all the controls and also can choose `holo-light` or `holo-dark` with custom colors you want.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

The SDK folder contains most of the themes, styles and drawables used in ICS. Check 
`SDK folder\platforms\android-15\data\res.`

You can apply themes/styles in your app like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)